# How to set base path for static files in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-routing, angular7-router

I have tried three approaches.

**1st : index.html**

```
<base href="/customer">
```

**2nd : app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/customer'}]
})
```

**3rd : app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/customer", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "customer",
    component: CustomerComponent,
    data: { animation: "HomePage" }
  }
];
```

All the above approaches work well for URL routing and I get desired URL.

http://localhost:4200/customer

However, static files(js & images) are still loading with the base path 'http://localhost:4200/'. I need it to have like http://localhost:4200/customer/main.js.

Hence, I am trying to make it http://localhost:4200/customer/main.js instead of http://localhost:4200/main.js for some secure validation reason.

Same can be seen in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `--baseHref` command line flag with `ng serve` and `ng build` this means that you  no longer have to prefix the routes in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
ng serve --baseHref=/customer/
```

build with

```
ng build --baseHref=/customer/
```

Comment: The application failed to load due to "http://localhost:4200/customer/runtime.js". It is not routing but it sets the relative path.

Comment: `ng serve --baseHref=/customer/`

Comment: Works for me when setting up a "Your First App" angular 7 project then used `ng serve --baseHref=/customer/`. The url http://localhost:4200/customer/ works without any error

Comment: It only works for me when I write the flag in the following way: `ng build --base-href=/customer/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--deploy-url` parameter in `ng build` command.

Example: `ng build --deploy-url /my/assets`

More detail on https://angular.io/guide/deployment.

Comment: The tooling says that this approach is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly same bug when I migrate from angular 5 to 7. It is probably related to the way that angular attaching the build js files. If you already added `<base href="/">` into index.html but the scripts are still loading from the relative path, it might because there is no `<body>` tag. Try add `<body>` tag into index.html file and see if it works.